# Étymologie de « voiture »

Tags: étymologie, transports

Wiktionary donne *vectura* (du latin « action de transporter ») comme origine étymologique de *voiture*.

Cependant le suffixe en *-ure* est utilisé pour indiquer la trace laissée par quelque action (cf wiktionary [suffix en -ure](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ure)).

Serait-ce correct de considérer que *voiture* est un glissement de sens de l'action de déplacer des objets ou des gens sur une voie (cf. la [9<sup>e</sup> définition du Littré](http://littre.reverso.net/dictionnaire-francais/definition/voiture)) ?

Comment: Et Charriote alors cousin Hubert, ça vient d'où ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Étymologie de *voiture*

Si je saisis bien la section étymologie du [Trésor de la Langue Française informatisé](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/voiture) (TLFi), *vectura* (dont *veiture* est la forme française d'origine selon le processus phonologique habituel, cf. *octo* → *huit*) est effectivement le terme latin dont *voiture* descend en ligne droite.

À l'origine, le terme semble désigner une charge transportée ou alors le coût dudit transport. Vers le 13e siècle, le sens avait dérivé jusqu'à signifier "Transport" ou "moyen de transport", avant de désigner éventuellement vers la fin du même siècle un type de véhicule à roue.

### Le suffixe *-ure*

*Vectura* est un dérivatif latin du verbe *vehere*, "aller". Dans ses sens les plus anciens, *voiture/veiture* n'est pas sémantiquement très différent de mots comme *bavure*, *ferrure* ou *courbure*. Des mots qui ont techniquement la même racine, mais des sens très éloignés de l'usage normal de ladite racine, on en trouve beaucoup: c'est par exemple réellement le suffixe *-age* qu'on retrouve dans *fromage* et *rivage*!

Comment: Merci pour cette réponse detaillée, si je la lis correctement elle semble confirmer mon intuition.

Answer (score 4):

L'Académie française définit [*voiture*](http://atilf.atilf.fr/) comme un « Moyen de transport consistant en une caisse montée sur des roues ».

Le Robert donne deux sources : *veiture* « moyen de transport » et *vectura* défini dans votre question.

La double étymologie se retrouve dans le sens : une caisse dotée de roues induit le déplacement d'un mobile sur une voie dédiée.

Selon la phrase ou l'intention on considérera l'objet immobile :

> Les voyageurs sont priés de regagner leur voiture, départ dans cinq
>   minutes.

ou en roulement (et non en glissement. N.B. le Robert ne donne qu'une définition pour *-URE* « suffixe indiquant que le composé chimique est un sel d'hydracide : *sulfure*, *chlorure*. »)

> Se déplacer en voiture.

qui vient des voitures (caisses avec porte(s) d'accès) tirées par des chevaux et a glissé sémantiquement vers *automobile* en fin de XX<sup>e</sup> siècle.

Comment: Merci pour cette piste prometteuse, un commentaire par "glissement" je pensais a une métonymie dont le résultat est le sens moderne de voiture et non a un transport par glissement.

Comment: @oberron Ce 'glissement' fait que l'argot devient étymologique en restituant à *caisse* sa définition d'origine en y ajoutant la puissance du moteur ; ce qui pourrait être une litote : dire peu : *boite à roue* pour beaucoup *voiture haut de gamme*.